# How does this switch debounce circuit work?

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis

I recently started learning about micro-electronics, specifically the Arduino. I'm slowly going through the Arduino cookbook and have hit something I don't really understand. The circuit is a simple debounce circuit but I'm having trouble fully understanding what each component is accomplishing and how the current is flowing.

In the picture and schematic below, why is the resistor used? Won't the capacitor by itself prevent switch debounce?

I don't quite understand the flow of current through this circuit. Won't current always use the other path to get to ground? When would current even flow through the resistor? Is the resistor solely there as a pull-down resistor and nothing more?

[image: Debounce Schematic]

[image: Debounce Circuit]

My goal is to fully understand each project as I work through it and I've been stuck on fully wrapping my head around this one for a week or so.

Comment: Note that you should use also a limiting resistor between +5V -> switch. A problem could be if D7 is used as "output" by "accident". How is wired the switch to +5V on your board?

Comment: @Antonio51, it's a reasonable idea but many/most boards don't actually add such a resistor though and it just pushes the cost up and board space and reliability down. Modern MCU design usually limits the current through a a shorted GPIO and prevents damage.

Comment: Right. So just move lowest pin resistor from ground to+5V and switch paralleled to capacitor (?) as in your second picture.

Comment: @Antonio51, then you'd have the same situation, able to drive the pin HIGH while it's shorted to ground (which my comment also covers). Same applies with the switch either way.

Comment: Right. No configuration is perfect. I prefer this one.

Comment: @Antonio51, quite, both the same with the one resistor. The switch to GND is usually preferred over the switch to 5 V, lower/no risk of VDD shorts if the switch is on the end of a cable by metalwork etc. You see the switch to GND configuration around far more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a parallel capacitor there is a variant on a common method for switch debounce. It works by slowing the fall time of the switch voltage and so requires the MCU to use a Schmitt trigger input for reading this slow-moving switch voltage.

The circuit you have is shown on the left below. On the right is the more commonplace form, found on many MCU/FPGA/etc demo' boards. The principles are the same.

For your circuit on the left, assuming R1 and C1 are suitable values for the SW1 max. bounce period...

1. At rest, consider Vsw1 to be GND as C1 has discharged through R1.
2. Pressing SW1 charges C1 quickly with the first contact(s). As the contacts bounce apart, C1 will discharge through R1. But Vsw1 will not fall below a good logic HIGH before the contacts bounce together again. That repeats until the pressed contacts stop bouncing. Vsw1 always reads a good logic HIGH in that time i.e. above the VIH(min) of the MCU input pin.
3. Releasing SW1 causes C1 to discharge through R1. Vsw1 falls relatively slowly to GND. As it passes through the indeterminate voltage range, between VIH(min) for a good logic HIGH and VIL(max) for a good logic LOW, the Schmitt trigger on the MCU input pin ensures a clean transition between detecting Vsw1 HIGH and detecting Vsw2 LOW.

Without the capacitor, any switch pressed contact bounces would produce a sort of HIGH-LOW-HIGH-LOW... noise waveform on Vsw1.

It can be considered is good practice for the MCU to then debounce the switch in software anyway but it's not a requirement.

C1 will draw a spike current from the supply as the switch contacts connect. It theory this is an infinite current at t0 but the components and track impedances stop this happening and local circuit decoupling will stop the supply rail dipping. As said, this is a very common circuit, used without problems in very large numbers of boards that I first saw 40 years ago.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMysre.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! That definitely helps clear things up. One follow on question - if C1 is discharged through R1 on the circuit on the left, what is the path the current takes for that discharge to happen? Sorry for the dumb question, I am just having trouble wrapping my head around how the resistor is discharging the capacitors current. Thanks!

Comment: @ubernoob1010, it's fine that you don't understand but you're asking about a basic of electronic circuits: how capacitors charge and discharge. In short, the stored charge on C1 creates a voltage across its terminals and so across R1. That causes a current flow through R1 which depletes that charge in C1, discharging it. In long, you can read up on 'RC discharge' for yourself on the internet, as this site can't be for tutorials. Try here for starters then search beyond, you'll plenty written in good detail.

Comment: TonyM, really appreciate all the help and you pointing me in the right direction. I'll do some studying on my own and I'm sure it'll all click with your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @ubernoob1010, you're very welcome :-)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you refer to the 10k R2, it keeps the pin voltage low so it reads low, and it keeps the capacitor discharged to 0V.

When you push the button, it will immediately charge the cap to 5V and make the MCU pin to read as high.

Releasing the button makes R2 discharge the cap slowly to 0V again.

There are no other current paths. There is no current through MCU, unless you configured it wrong.

And suddely shorting a cap to charge to 5V involves a huge surge of current, which likely is not good for the capacitor, or for the button, or for the supply voltage if it dips due to large current spike, and the resulting current surge in a wire loop also creates a magnetic pulse likely to disturb communications of nearby RF devices.

Cookbook circuits are just simple examples to introduce a concept and may be poor examples. In real life you could just omit the capacitor and be done with it. Or at least use a different circuit.

Doing button debouncing with resistors and capacitors may even make things worse, and they don't tell you this in cookbooks, the people who wrote the cookbook may just be a hobbyist like you and may not be electrical engineers who really understand what's going on, or don't think that these advanced concepts are relevant to beginner hobbyists.

The RC circuit causes the voltage to drop slowly, and slow voltages on digital inputs are also problematic. The voltage can be at a threshold between logic 0 and 1 for a long time and any noise can make the CPU to determine it switches between 0 and 1 at high frequency.

This may for example trigger interrupts multiple times even if the button is pushed only once and even if the button does not bounce.

And a voltage sitting at right at the threshold of logic 0 and 1 will turn on both FETs of a CMOS input and excess current is consumed.

Answer (score 4):

The [ATmega328P](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/ATMega328.pdf) chip used in your Arduino Uno has an input hysteresis of about 430mV when powered from 5V (the datasheet has an error, as confirmed by SamGibson in a comment below. It is volts, not mV, which would be ridiculously small).

[image]

If the switch happens to bounce open when the capacitor voltage is near the threshold about 2.3V then the 100nF capacitor will discharge at an intial rate of about dv/dt = 2.3V/(10KΩ * 100nF) = -2.3kV/s, so it will traverse the hysteresis band in about 200usec. That's not adequate time for typical switch bounce times of several milliseconds, though probably works with a variety of switches since it's unlikely the switch will close then bounce open at the precise worst-case point in time, especially since the switch will tend to weld a bit with the circuit shown.

Note that it's also introducing a negative-going **transient** into the power supply (which is  most unwelcome) at the instant the switch closes. I would much prefer to see the switch across the capacitor and the pullup resistor to +5V. The original Uno [schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf) shows several 100nF caps and a 47uF electrolytic in parallel, meaning that the 5V supply voltage could momentarily drop by more than a volt for a couple microseconds when the switch closes. Not good. It's also poorly controlled since it depends on capacitor(s) ESR, wiring resistance and inductance and switch resistance.

The resistor is necessary to make the switch work, it is not (directly) related to the debouncing, but of course it plays a part.

It's generally better to use firmware (eg. poll at a frequency around 1kHz and accept the reading when it is stable for 'long enough' -- where 'long enough' is a function of the switch construction) since you have an MCU to work with. Sometimes a small capacitor (eg. 10nF) is still recommended by switch and mechanical encoder manufacturers.

Half-measure debouncing schemes can appear to work fine with a brand new switch but fail as the switch ages, so some care is called for if reliability is of any importance.

Comment: Hi Spehro, Just regarding that datasheet - Agreed, as you say, that hysteresis graph axis label must be an error. [Here](https://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/65d19a89a4a2dbc52152b0afb98c31e87906937c/13atmega328_p20avr20mcu20with20picopower20technology20data20sheet20.pdf) is another version of the ATmega328P datasheet that I found (18MB PDF) which has an almost identical hysteresis graph on p391 (Figure 33-27) with the vertical axis labeled as *volts* this time.

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks, that confirms it. I'll leave the original  graph as a warning to anyone using the older/Sparkfun dasheet and edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. it's not a good circuit. When the switch is closed, the switch tries to charge the cap instantly, which means it takes a high current (limited only by the power supply and the low resistance of wires/traces), which can eventually cause the switch to fail.

You can however leave the cap out and things should then be OK.

Almost certainly the switch debouncing is done in software, not in hardware. So the answer to your question lies in the code, not the schematic.

Comment: Charging a 100 nF capacitor is so fast, it would not be a problem. Much bigger capacitors would be a problem for the switch. Of course the current to the cap is limited by the inductivity of the traces too.